# Passing image data using xmlType is not received in blob variable

Tags: java, oracle11g, xmltype

I am passing xml doc to Oracle procedure and receiving as xmlType. To save image data there is one field fruitImage in xml field. I try to store content of imageField in v_fruitImage variable but I am getting database error 'ORA-01706: user function result value was too large'. Below is code:

1. Xml Doc

`<fruit fruitId="4" fruitName="mango" fruitImage="ZGF0YTppbWFnZS9qcGVnO2Jhc2U2NCwvOWovNEFBUVNrWkpSZ0FCQVFBQUFRQUJBQUQvL2dBN1ExSkZRVlJQVWpvZ1oyUXRhbkJsWnlCMk1TNHdJQ2gxYzJsdVp5QkpTa2NnU2xCRlJ5QjJPREFwTENCeGRXRnNhWFI1SUQwZ09EQUsvOXNBUXdBR0JBVUdCUVFHQmdVR0J3Y0dDQW9RQ2dvSkNRb1VEZzhNRUJjVUdCZ1hGQllXR2gwbEh4b2JJeHdXRmlBc0lDTW1KeWtxS1JrZkxUQXRLREFsS0Nr........(very big length)">
.....
.....
</fruit>`

2. Statement to extract value from xml.

   SELECT 
     Fr.fruitId 
     ,Fr.fruitName 
     ,Fr.fruitImage
   INTO 
     v_fruitId,
     v_fruitName,
     v_fruitImage
   FROM
   XMLTABLE('/fruit' PASSING i_xml
   COLUMNS fruitId INT PATH '@fruitId'
   ,fruitName CHAR(1) PATH '@fruitName'
   ,fruitImage BLOB PATH '@fruitImage'
   ) Fr;

Please help me how to store image field from xml document to a BLOB variable.

Comment: xml document is:
<fruit fruitId="4" fruitName="mango" fruitImage="ZGF0YTppbWFnZS9qcGVnO2Jhc2U2NCwvOWovN................>
......
......
......
</fruit>

Comment: Please add additional information by clicking the edit link under your question, not by leaving a comment. That way, it can be correctly formatted (and you don't have a very small size limit).

Comment: I have put same text in question section visible in above comment, but it is not appearing. Not sure about the reason.